# Semantic-ui react modal shorthand prevent button closing modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

Using the code on the docs page shown below for a shorthand modal, how do i stop the button from closing the modal in the actions property? Ive tried preventDefault, no luck, its got me stumped?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const ModalExampleShorthand = () => (
  <Modal
    trigger={<Button>Show Modal</Button>}
    header='Reminder!'
    content='Call Benjamin regarding the reports.'
    actions={['Snooze', { key: 'done', content: 'Done', positive: true }]}
  />
)

export default ModalExampleShorthand
```

Comment: Can you please add all the code of the component? Including the imports?

Comment: hi Atin, code updated.

Comment: Basically you don't want the modal to close on clicking of snooze and done buttons?

Comment: yep, keep it open when clicked, use a handle event instead.

Answer (score 1):

Cant believe I didnt think of this, I just needed to add onClick handler in the actions, ie:

```
actions={['Snooze', { key: 'done', content: 'Done', positive: true, onClick: myFunc }]}
```